# Check if object is based on jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm creating an array of objects based on some buttons on the page. When I click one of the buttons I want to iterate through the array and see if it matches the button just clicked. Obviously there currently is no match as it is trying to compare objects to a jquery object - so different types. How can I get this into a format where I can make the comparison?

```
dropdowns = []

$('.dropdown').each (index, el) =>
    dropdown = new Dropdown(el: $(el))
    dropdowns.push(dropdown)

$('.dropdown').on 'click', ->
    dropdown = @
    $.each dropdowns, (index, el) =>
        if dropdown == el
            alert 'match'
```

`new Dropdown` creates a new coffeescript class with a few methods such as `.show()` `.hide()` etc

Thanks

Comment: You could assign the `Dropdown` instance to the element via `.data`, then you don't even have to compare.  Or you bind the event handler inside `Dropdown`.

Comment: Did you try `if dropdown[0] == el`

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks but the real world scenario is a bit more complicated so don't think they are options with what I'm actually trying to do - I simplified this so it was accessible. Real js is here http://jsfiddle.net/MZJfM/2/ and it's using uniform https://github.com/DrPheltRight/uniform

Comment: Then you could access the jQuery object of the `Dropdown` instance and  the underlying DOM element and compare it to `dropdown`. I don't know CoffeeScript, you might have to provide a method wich lets you access the jQuery object of a `Dropdown` instance.

Comment: I am attaching data to the element `dropdown = new Dropdown(el: $el)` 
`$el.data('dropdown', dropdown)` is there anyway to then later check if the instance of the class that we're comparing when we iterate through them all is the same as the instance we assigned to data on the element?

Comment: You don't have to compare anymore. You want the corresponding `Dropdown` instance to the clicked element, right? Then you can just do `var dropdown = $(this).data('dropdown')`. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @FelixKling Sure, but with that I get `[object Object]` (at least that's what it console.log's) which returns false when I compare `if el == dropdown.data('dropdown')`

Comment: @FelixKling Oh and yes I still need to compare as I'm iterating through all dropdowns on the page and making sure they are not the one I have just clicked on `el.hide() unless el is dropdown.data('dropdown')`

Answer (score 0):

Usually you just need to use $(), for example:

```
$(obj) //gives the jquery object for obj
```

Comment: Well, it gives *a* jQuery object. Two calls to jQuery return different objects, i.e. `$(obj) === $(obj)` is `false`.